# $(ProjectDir) in post deployment SQL files

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, sqlcmd, dacpac

I want to use `$(ProjectDir)` the one available under macro in pre- and post-deployment scripts instead of hard coding path.

I tried

```
:setvar tpath '$(ProjectDir)'
Print $(tpath)
```

This is just printing `$(ProjectDir)`, looks like it's considering as string.

Even I tried defining under SQLCMD Variable, it's same issue.